# Facebook open graph warnings that should be fixed: Parser Mismatched Metadata

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

My Wordpress website is [Koh Samui](http://kohsamui.co.uk/)

I have this warning in fb debuger: Facebook open graph warnings that should be fixed:

Parser Mismatched Metadata.

When I try and post one of my posts on fb, fb shows my contact details page and not the post.

Please see [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://kohsamui.co.uk/index.php/2012/05/6123/)

Comment: Would be great if i could get some help with my above question. Any advise would be great!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some leading white space in your description. Facebook don't like that, apparently.  You also have multiple values for `type` and `title` on the one page - I think they want each page to be a separate object.

Comment: Hi rgchris, I have only just seen your reply! thank you so much for your advice. i will look into this.

Comment: Would also like to add they don't like white space at the end either, which caused my problem with this same error message.